# Overriding a method which uses a subtype

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I have an abstract class having an abstract method:

```
public abstract SomeClass Do(SomeClass o1, SomeClass o2);
```

Then when I implement in a concrete class which extends that abstract class which has the method from before it I get an error:

```
@Override 
public AClass Do(AClass o1, AClass o2) //AClass extends Someclass
{
//
}
```

Why do I get the error since AClass is a subtype of SomeClass?

The error is: The method ... must override or implement a super-type method

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get an error because it doesn't support the same interface. Imagine a caller like this:

```
AbstractClass x = new ImplementingClass();
x.Do(new SomeClass(), new SomeClass());
```

That *should* work - it's just using the `AbstractClass` abstract method, right? But the values you're passing in aren't `AClass` references, they're just `SomeClass` references.

Your *return type* is okay, but the parameters you're declaring are "narrower" than the original API, so your method can't handle all the calls that the original method could, and so can't override it.